# Is it possible to shut down cassandra cluster and restart it back without loosing data?

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, datastax

Im running 2 node cassandra cluster on virtual box (one as a seed). I need to shut down the cluster and turn it on again. But when i tried to restart, it is throwing an error "cannot change the number of tokens from 1 to 256", even though i dint change any configuration. But i am able to restart it after deleting the data. Is there any way to restart the cluster without removing the data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have changed your cassandra.yaml to include num_tokens to 256 on a cluster that was using single tokens.

Comment out num_tokens and try again.

Comment: ya i got it. i commented out the num_tokens. Its working fine now.